# Using jquery ajax, I make a POST request to an external page. Why does it load each css/JS file as seperate GET requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

A lot of these pages are like mini applications that have their own CSS and JS files. So, the requested page is loaded, then the style sheets and javascript files are loaded one by one. It does this when I output the returned page using jquery .html().

Is this "just the way it works" or am I missing something? Here is a link to an image showing the firebug console output: http://freelife.com/images/fb_console.jpg

Example code:

```
$.ajax({
async: true,
type: "POST",
url: url,
cache: false,
dataType: "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
success: function(data) {

    $("div#comp_tab").html(data);

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this "just the way it works" or am I missing something?

It is the way it works. When you send an AJAX request to an HTML page that could potentially contain references to other resources (scripts, styles, images, ...) and you inject this HTML into the DOM, the web browser will send separate requests to fetch those resources in order to display them. They are not retrieved as part of the original AJAX request.

Comment: In Chrome/Firefox, check your Network panel and see how many GET requests occur on any page. Every external file: JS, CSS, IMG.

Comment: An AJAX request simply fetches the raw data and only when it is parsed and loaded as HTML through the injection does the browser load the resources. They have only then become requested.

Comment: I don't know much about JSON but would that help? Inotherwords, is there a way to load the entire external resource as an "object" that can then be displayed in its entirety? I noticed that if I change async to false I almost get the desired result (looking in firebug) but I can't get it displayed in the browser.

Comment: JSON is an interoperable serialization format that allows you to send messages between different systems.